# Maintaining type inference when aliasing columns in knex

Tags: typescript, knex.js

Suppose I have two tables: `A` and `B` with each row typed as

```
type ARow = {
  primaryId: number;
  name: string
};

type BRow = {
  foreignId: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Knex is clever enough to infer the types of results of selecting from each table:

```
// aList is inferred to be of type { primaryId: number, name: string }[]
const aList = await knex<ARow>("a").select("primaryId", "name")
```

This can even be done with aliasing (so long as we only reference the column name not the table):

```
// aList is inferred to be of type { id: number, description: string }[]
const aList = await knex<ARow>("a").select({
  id: "primaryId",
  description: "name",
})
```

However both `A` and `B` have a `name` that I would like to alias separately:

```
// joined is inferred to be of type { id: any, aName: any, bName: any }[]
const joined = await knex<ARow>("a")
  .join<BRow>("b", "primaryId", "foreignId")
  .select({
    id: "primaryId",
    aName: "a.name",
    bName: "b.name",
  })
```

Is there anyway to retain the type safety while aliasing columns based on the table?

Answer (score 1):

```
const joined = knex<ARow>("a")
    .join<BRow>("b", "primaryId", "foreignId")
    .select(
        knex.ref("primaryId"),
        knex.ref("name").as("aName").withSchema("a"),
        knex.ref("name").as("bName").withSchema("b")
    );
```